# Gitlab: How to check if a string is one of three values

Tags: bash, gitlab

We'd like to ensue that a user enters a value from a list of valid options. Since we found no way to define a preset of valid values, we are currently trying do it with an if statement.

However we have trouble finding out the if syntax for a OR operator.

**What we currently have:**

```
variables:
    BUMP_TYPE: 'no-release-just-build'
...
  before_script:
      - >
        if [[ "$BUMP_TYPE" = "no-release-just-build"] || ["$BUMP_TYPE" = "patch" ]]; then
          echo "valid $BUMP_TYPE"
        else
          echo "invalid $BUMP_TYPE"
        fi
```

However this outputs: "invalid no-release-just-build" --> **the else case**

Why is `"$VERSION" = "no-release-just-build"` not true?

Comment: What is the value of ${VERSION} ?

Comment: Sorry, I past an old version of my test.. $VERSION should be $BUMP_TYPE

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net). Two general notes: First, those square brackets are not parentheses; don't try to use them as parentheses. Second, spaces *matter* in shell syntax; if you could use square brackets the way you're trying to, you'd need spaces between them and the strings you're trying to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little Different approach, what I like to do - instead of bash scripting within the script - is a job in the pre stage based on rules like

```yaml
Param-check:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - echo "invalid version:$VERSION - please use ..."
    - exit 1
  rules:
    - if: $VERSION == "value1"
      when: never
    - if: '$VERSION == "value1" || $VERSION == "value2"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

This way I keep my script and before blocks clean of validations

There is also the possibility to use regex for the rules, but I am on my mobile, and therefore writing regex is ultra hard - i also could not validate my script. But I think I show the general idea

Comment: I forgot the important part... And I can not luck it up ;( the `exit 1;`

Comment: I am trying to ci lint this with my mobile ;) i do my best

Comment: i validated the yaml now with ci lint, and it should be working - sorry for the inconvinience