# Gitlab: Make required variables when running pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want the some of the variables should be required before executing the pipeline in gitlab.
Can I achieve it.
I have below gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:          # Runs First - Anything that needs to run prior to your scripts running
  - deploy
  - Script

variables:
  Domain:
    value: "dom"
  HOST_NAME:
    value: ""  
  JAVA_FILES_WITH_ARGS:
    value: ""
```

I want to make mandatory(JAVA_FILES_WITH_ARGS, HOST_NAME) before run the pipeline how can I achieve it. it will not start the pipeline without these two variable values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674002/gitlab-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-one-of-three-values/69674178#69674178 might be the right approach

Comment: Simon how to give custom error mesage instead "No stages and Pipeline" when it allow not to proceed

Answer (score 1):

The Answer: is

```
rules:
 - if: '$JAVA_FILES_WITH_ARGS != "" && $HOST_NAME != ""'
   allow_failure: true
```

Comment: @Kappacake i've made the suggested edits